# How To Add Custom Ribbon Action for "SPECIFIC" List/Libraries in SharePoint Online

Tags: sharepoint-online

I have created a custom ribbon action for library. But, this custom action shown in all library exists in my SharePoint. I want custom action only for **specific** library.

Please help me to display custom action only for specific library/list.

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 0):

You can create Custom Action by using SharePoint Designer.

Open Lists/libraries with SharePoint Designer->Click Custom Action->View Ribbon->Create Custom Action.

[image]

Then the extra form will show up in the Ribbon.

Refer to the following links:

http://www.abelsolutions.com/totm/creating-a-custom-action-in-2-steps-with-sharepoint-designer/

https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/adding-custom-action-to-the-ribbon-of-view-in-sharepoint-list-library/

Comment: Thanks for your response.but, I want to add custom action using Element.xml file (Module) in Sharepoint project.